# Pandas: Filtering data based on information from multiple dataframes

Tags: pandas

I am analyzing clinical data and trying to filter out information in one dataframe based on information from another dataframe.

One of the dataframes lists dates that patients come in for treatment

```
dfTreatments = pd.DataFrame({'PatientID': [4,4,4,9,9,9,11,11,11], 'TreatmentDate': ['2016-01-01', '2016-01-15', '2016-03-25','2016-01-01','2016-01-15','2016-01-29','2016-01-01','2016-03-15','2016-03-25']})
dfTreatments['TreatmentDate'] = pd.to_datetime(dfTreatments['TreatmentDate'])

   PatientID TreatmentDate
0          4    2016-01-01
1          4    2016-01-15
2          4    2016-03-25
3          9    2016-01-01
4          9    2016-01-15
5          9    2016-01-29
6         11    2016-01-01
7         11    2016-03-15
8         11    2016-03-25
```

and the other dataframe lists dates that patients visit a hospital with a complication.

```
dfHospitalVisits = pd.DataFrame({'PatientID': [4,4,9,11], 'HospitalVisitDate': ['2016-01-14','2016-03-10','2016-01-28','2016-01-03']})
dfHospitalVisits['HospitalVisitDate'] = pd.to_datetime(dfHospitalVisits['HospitalVisitDate'])

  HospitalVisitDate  PatientID
0        2016-01-14          4
1        2016-03-10          4
2        2016-01-28          9
3        2016-01-03         11
```

In our study, we want to exclude hospital visits from our analysis if the patient **does not receive treatment for 20 days**. We **start excluding them at the last treatment before the 20 day gap**. E.g.: We would exclude any hospital visits for patient 4 after 2016-01-15.

In this example, *Patient 4's 2nd hospital visit* and *Patient 11's hospital visit* would be removed from dfHospitalVisits.

Edit: @Merlin, so far I have used `dfTreatments.groupby('PatientID')['TreatmentDate'].diff()` to get me the gaps in treatment dates grouped by patient. The part where I am stuck is that I don't know how to use a difference in treatment dates that is >20 to filter out values in dfHospitalVisits .

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Look at this for ideas. http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_join_merge_dataframe.html

Comment: You need to look at link provided.  SO isnt a coding service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
# Make a sorted dataframe to calculate the time gap before the next treatment 
dfTreatments_sorted = dfTreatments.sort_values(['PatientID','TreatmentDate'], ascending=False)

# Calculate the time gap before the next treatment
df_diff = dfTreatments_sorted.groupby('PatientID').TreatmentDate.diff(periods=1).rename('Gap_before_next_treatment')

# Add the time gaps as a new column to your existing dfTreatments dataframe
dfTreatments = pd.concat([dfTreatments, -df_diff], axis=1, join='inner').sort_index()

# Join dfTreatments and dfHospitalVisits into new dataframe (df)
df = dfHospitalVisits.set_index('PatientID').join(dfTreatments.set_index('PatientID'))

# Select combination where TreatmentDate is before corresponding HospitalVisitDate
df = df[(df.HospitalVisitDate>df.TreatmentDate)]

# The TreatmentDate that is important is latest before the HospitalVisitDate
df = df.reset_index().groupby(['PatientID','HospitalVisitDate']).max()

# Now you can filter hospital visits given the calculated time gap
df = df[df.Gap_before_next_treatment<'20 days'].reset_index()[['PatientID','HospitalVisitDate']]
```